# Does IBM Cloud Load Balancer support WebSocket?

Tags: load-balancing, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

According to Docs, it says below.

-Support for HTTP, HTTPS and TCP-based applications
[IBM Cloud Load Balancer](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/infrastructure/loadbalancer-service?topic=loadbalancer-service-about-ibm-cloud-load-balancer&locale=en)

Doesn't IBM Cloud Load Balancer support ws (WebSocket) or wss (WebSocket Secure) protocol?

Comment: Websockets are TCP based. WS(S) is a protocol based on top of the HTTP(S) which in turn is built on top of TCP.

Comment: Thank you @emix. I heard some load balancers discards upgrade-header. if so we can not build connection with web-socket server behind such kind of load balancer.
If we can not configure ibm cloud load balancer timeout and it's default timeout is short, websocket connection would cut off in a short time.